# to get keypad in Iphone

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova

I am developing an app in IOS/android with cordova 2.1.0. In index.html file,
i am using following in anchor tag to get the keypad with phone number pre-populated in android:

```
href="tel:'+messagePhoneArray[i]+'"
```

Is is the same used to get keypad in iphone also or anything else is required. I have IPod but don't have iphone to test it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will initiate a call to `messagePhoneArray[i]` on iPhone and also some other platforms too.